# Why won't my GeForce® GTX 560 Ti 2GB (2048MB GDDR5) find my third monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have installed the graphics card and upgraded the PSU on a Dell Optiplex360 so that I can run three monitors.

I run a taxi office and need three monitors for booking and dispatch. Can anybody tell me why I can't get the computer to see the third monitor?

Answer (score 5):

While the card has 3 outputs (2 x DVI-I, 1 x HDMI) only two of them are active at any one time. The maximum resolution quoted [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html) is 2560x1600 which is 2 screens at 1280x1600.

To get a third monitor you'll need a 2<sup>nd</sup> graphics card.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was told by scan that this would do the job. And in the literature it says that it will run up to 4 monitors, two dvi one VGA and one hdmi. Have I been mis sold?

Comment: @Nodstar - I did see another page that had the card with 4 outputs, but I thought the nVidia page was more authoritative. Can you post a link to the literature you saw - assuming it's on-line.

Comment: Sorry Chris the literature that comes with it. The link to the product at Scan is http://www.scan.co.uk/products/72gb-palit-gtx-560-ti-40nm-4008mhz-gddr5-gpu-822mhz-shader-1645mhz-384-cores-2x-dvi-hdmi-vga#ProductFeatures  thanks

Comment: My bad Chris I've just got into work and it says (multiple) monitors. This still means two I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

If you card is really from [shown here](http://www.scan.co.uk/products/72gb-palit-gtx-560-ti-40nm-4008mhz-gddr5-gpu-822mhz-shader-1645mhz-384-cores-2x-dvi-hdmi-vga#ProductFeatures) type - you **can use 3  monitors**

- DVI
- VGA
- HDMI